# В каком порядке рассматриваются тревоги?

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги, история-тревог

Просматривал свою историю, и до сих пор висят тревоги, которые были 2 дня назад, хотя другие тревоги, которые были день, час назад, давно уже проверили. Складывается ощущение, что очереди тревог, аналогичной очереди проверок, просто нет.

<s>Не</s> искал в справке и на мете — ничего не нашёл.

---

> [image: Скриншот №1]

> [image: Скриншот №2]

Answer (score 5):

Да, тревоги показываются в админке не по одной, а массово списком плашек. У каждой плашки показано, кто из модераторов посмотрел вопрос после появления тревоги. Можно посмотреть тревогу и ничего с ней не сделать, можно оставить комментарий или произвести ещё какие-то действия, но при этом не снимать тревогу.

Обработка разных тревог может занимать разное время и требовать разных усилий. Среднее время обработки тревоги за последний месяц на основном сайте - 3 часа 21 минута.

Ещё стоит заметить, что не все тревоги обрабатываются модераторами, некоторые тревоги хотя и могут быть обработаны модератором, предназначены для отправки сообщения в одну из очередей проверок.

[image: скриншот]

PS: @αλεχολυτ, добавил [статус-завершено](/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be) по этим двум тревогам.

Comment: Ещё бы по двум старинным решение принять :) Но, видимо, это может быть политическим самоубийством, если свободу воли проявить.

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я знаю, у модераторов нет какой-либо очереди проверки тревог. Есть просто список, из которого можно взять ту или иную и как-то на неё прореагировать (или вернуть обратно в список для дальнейшего рассмотрения). Если модератор по каким-то причинам не хочет брать тревогу на рассмотрение, то такая тревога может провисеть достаточно времени (и вроде как может даже протухнуть, но это не точно), пока какой-то более ответственный (или смелый) участник с ромбом (может даже SOтрудник, а не простой модератор) возьмёт на себя задачу по проверке тревоги.

Выборы прошли, обещания электорат проглотил, теперь можно и отдохнуть от модераторских забот. Никакой обязанности проверять тревоги за определённый временной интервал у модераторов нет.

У меня тоже висят в ожидании пара тревог десятидневной давности, а одна вчерашняя обработана. Но это Мета, тут вообще всё медленнее происходит, пока не пнёшь - не полетит, условно.

Comment: Как-то вы негативно настроены по отношению к электорату и выборам. Может лучше убрать этот абзац?

Comment: @Kromster я к электорату позитивно настроен, потому и не выдвигался. А вот к действующим модераторам ... точнее, к их деятельности, уже несколько иначе.

Comment: NB: Тревоги типа "требуется вмешательство модератора" с указанной причиной не протухают от времени.

Comment: @Kromster зачем? Автор высказал свое мнение, которое имеет право на жизнь, без матов и прочего. Или у нас модерация/моралфажество/прогибание перед меньш... сообществом уже везде?))

Comment: @DaemonHK для меня *"Содержимое данного сообщения неуместно в контексте уважительной беседы."*. Где у вас там прогибания - мне не ведомо.

Answer (score 2):

Расскажу за себя.

1. Проверяю обычно тревоги с утра (если это важно то *MSK*) - разбираю их по очереди
2. Обычно примерно 90% тревог разбираются быстро, 5% бывают сложными, а еще 5% довольно сложными. При разборе сложных, если у меня есть сомнения то я оставляю их другим модераторам.
3. Через 5-6 часов захожу, опять разбираю тревоги и если среди них есть старые неразобранные засучив рукава начинаю разбираться и с ними.
4. На выходных редко разбираю тревоги
5. По ряду причин тревоги на мете я не рассматриваю - пару раз отхватил от опытных модеров потом решил: *"ну_вас_на_фик_разбирайтесь_с_тревогами_на_мете_сами"*

Comment: С метой надо бы возвращаться к обработке тревог. Мета это тоже под модераторской ответственностью. Но за честность спасибо.