# Как "красиво" вставить скриншот с SO?

Tags: обсуждение, изображения

[Повод](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11011/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3) для этого вопроса. Я сделал скриншот моей истории проверок и обрезал её, но получилось так, что он сливается с фоном div'а с текстом вопроса. Пытался разграничить с помощью `---` (Markdown), но такие же разделители есть и на самом скриншоте истории тревог, из-за чего никакого разделения не происходит. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ добавить тень к изображению, или сделать какую-то рамку для него (кроме <s>Paint'а</s> графического редактора растровых изображений, конечно)?

Comment: Наверняка можно, но, по-моему, с графикой это сделать проще: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jABda.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Раньше было удобно делать цитирование, как пишет EOF в своём ответе. Но с недавних пор дизайн цитирования был изменён и выглядит иначе, чем был раньше.

Раньше была заметная рамка вокруг всего изображения, что устраняло эффект слияния с окружающим текстом и страницей, а теперь просто вертикальная полоса слева, не дающая такого эффекта. Я по старой привычке (и с надеждой, что всё же когда-нибудь снова появится рамка) добавляю цитирование.

Вот, есть фича-реквест, чтобы вернуть жёлтый фон (а-ля рамку) для цитат:
[Please revert the quote background from white to yellow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344874/339911) Можете проголосовать.

Ещё хочу заметить, что в мобильных приложениях Stack Exchange (ныне фактически не поддерживаемых, но всё же работоспособных в целом) выделение цитат осталось прежним. Т.о. хотя бы пользователи приложений (я лично пользуюсь регулярно) могут наблюдать эти "красиво" вставленные скриншоты, если продолжать пользоваться выделением типа "цитирование".

Answer (score 3):

> Можно поместить изображение в цитату.

> > Можно даже в двойную цитату.

> > > Ну и тройную никто не отменял:)

Comment: ну, двойная — это уже слишком... <s>даже для меня.</s>

Comment: опять забыл, что `<s>` не работает...

Comment: нужно БОЛЬШЕ [вложенности](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/11013/revisions)!!!

Comment: мы можем улучшить этот ответ!

Comment: @return https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325460/865952